# why obtain an access token / appId / apisecret from Facebook and/or should I store them?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, oauth

Why do I need to obtain an access token? Also, should I store this? Would I need to get other information? For example, facebook as appId and ApiSecret. What is the benefit of getting these? Also, should I store any of these?

If I store these into mysql when user logs into do I need the user to check against it? before logging in? I don't understand if this makes sense because first time users don't have these information?

Would these expire? So would I have to constantly check and replace my old one when user logs in? or if they keep coming to my page?

I'm currently messing around with facebook's php sdk and I don't have any of these in my sql yet, but I'm able to still build an input field on my page and pass it into my facebook's feed. I'm able to get user's information and other stuff, but why would I need access token/appid/apisecret?

Thanks! I'm so confused!

Comment: don't use them and see what happens :). but seriously, that's how it works, read zombat's answer, it explains everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.Why do I need to obtain an access token?**

access tokens are proofs that you application has required permissions to use currently logged on users information.

**2.should I store this?**

Not required .your SDK will automatically obtain them with your appid when user will connect to your application using facebook.

**3. Would I need to get other information( facebook as appId and ApiSecret)?**

Yes,They are required for facebook to autenticate your app.You need to initialize your SDK with theese.

**4.If I store these into mysql when user logs into do I need the user to check against it? before logging in?**

After you initialize your app with APP ID and SECRET .you can get the id of the current facebook user
You can save in your database 
FacebookID->UserID for your users in your  website.

If current FacebookID matchs with your users s in your  website. you can log them in else redirect to registration form

**5.Would these expire?**
That would be handled by SDK.You only need to check if the currently logged in facebook user is user for your site.APPID and APPSECRET dont expire.

**6.why would I need access token/appid/apisecret?**
Because  OAuth 2.0 involves three different steps: user authentication, app authorization and app authentication.
Refer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to interact with Facebook's API in any way, you need to identify yourself to Facebook.  That's what the access token is for.  It allows you to make calls to Facebook's API using that token, and Facebook knows it's you.

Application ids and secrets are given to you when you register a Facebook application (https://developers.facebook.com/apps).  The App ID and App Secret are unique values for use in API calls such as posting news feeds from your app/site.  When you use them as part of the PHP SDK, you can make API calls involving/about/using a user that has given your application permission to do so (such as fetching their information, group permissions, etc).

If you are trying to integrate Facebook authentication into a website, you will need to register an application in order to do so.  As part of the login process for the first time, a user will be asked to give your website permission to access their Facebook information, which is then subsequently used in the login process.

You generally do not need to store access tokens or your App Id/App Secret in a database.  The Facebook PHP SDK takes care of handling these things for you in normal usage.  The reason you are probably able to send an input field to Facebook right now is that you are probably currently logged in to Facebook, and it's using your session cookie to do it.

If you haven't already, you probably want to do some reading at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/.

Comment: I've read the documentation but I'm just a little bit confused on the overall concept. I'm still new to developing... So I logged out of my facebook, and I noticed that my website now is logged out as well. Basically its connected to facebook. So if I get the `offline_access` permission in user login, I would need to implement access token?